# Average of 10 readings, wrong

Tags: sensors

I am reading from loadcell and calculating the average of last 10 readings. But when the load cell reads something more than 3800 g the average gets negative, how? The mass I read are not negative numbers. I have been trying to find my mistake but I am not able to. Any help?

```
#include "HX711.h"

const int numReadings = 10;
const int LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN = 8;
const int LOADCELL_SCK_PIN = 10;
int readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int readIndex = 0;              // the index of the current reading
int total = 0;                  // the running total
int average = 0;                // the average
int mass  =0;
long reading = 0;

HX711 scale;

float a = 0.0088;
float b = 2009.7;


void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication with computer:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize all the readings to 0:
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) {
    readings[thisReading] = 0;
  }
  scale.begin(LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN, LOADCELL_SCK_PIN);
}

void loop() {
  if (scale.is_ready()) {
    // read from the sensor:
    reading = scale.read();
    // convert to mass  
    mass = int((a*reading)-b);
    // subtract the last reading:
    total = total - readings[readIndex];
   
    Serial.print(int((a*reading)-b));
    readings[readIndex] = mass;
    // add the reading to the total:
    total = total + readings[readIndex];
    // advance to the next position in the array:
    readIndex = readIndex + 1;
  
    // if we're at the end of the array...
    if (readIndex >= numReadings) {
      // ...wrap around to the beginning:
      readIndex = 0;
    }
  
    // calculate the average:
    average = total / numReadings;
    // send it to the computer as ASCII digits
    
    Serial.print("   ");
    Serial.print(average);
    Serial.println("");
    delay(1000);        // delay in between reads for stability
  }
  else{
    Serial.print("loadcell not found!");
  }
}
```

Comment: It's called "integer wraparound" - `int` can only hold between -32768 and +32767 on an 8-bit Arduino.

Comment: Omg, thank you very much for the help. I was struggling with it

Comment: tip, if you know that it only should contain positive numbers, declare as an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be use 'long' as a variable type for total.   Depending on your application, you also might look into an exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA); it can de-emphasize older data points, if that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented by Majenko, the problem in integer wraparound. One solution would be to get rid of that `total` variable and calculate every new average based on the previous average and the mass you are replacing in the array, using this formula:

```
new_average = old_average + (mass - readings[readIndex]) / numReadings
```

So your code would look like:

```
  if (scale.is_ready()) {
    // read from the sensor:
    reading = scale.read();
    // convert to mass  
    mass = int((a*reading)-b);

    // calculate the new average:
    new_average = average + (mass - readings[readIndex]) / numReadings;
   
    Serial.print(int((a*reading)-b));
    readings[readIndex] = mass;

    // advance to the next position in the array:
    readIndex = readIndex + 1;
  
    // if we're at the end of the array...
    if (readIndex >= numReadings) {
      // ...wrap around to the beginning:
      readIndex = 0;
    }
  
    // set the average:
    average = new_average;

    // send it to the computer as ASCII digits
    Serial.print("   ");
    Serial.print(average);
    Serial.println("");
    delay(1000);        // delay in between reads for stability
  }
```

Just don't forget to add a declaration for `new_average` to the beginning of your code.